# Экспорт текста в svg

Tags: html, дизайн, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, как правильно экспортировать файл из корела в svg? Я дизайнер, экспортирую картинку с текстом, размер которого 24п., а программисты говорят, что шрифт гигантский 70 000px, в чем и где может быть ошибка?

И еще вопрос по градиенту, в кореле я вижу одно, при экспорте градиент съезжает и меняется, в чем тут причина?

Answer (score 1):

SVG может просто не поддерживать какие-то хитрые варианты градиента которые умеет корел и которые вы используете.

Возможно в кореле есть возможность при создании проекта указать что его нужно будет экспортировать в SVG, что-бы корел использовал только те фичи которые может выразить в SVG.

*Обновление*

P.S. если картинка большая и сложная то есть смысл задуматься разумно-ли вставлять её на сайт в виде вектора. Растеризация вектора задача довольно-таки ресурсоёмкая, а весить сложный вектор может ощутимо больше растра.

Comment: спасибо! а что может быть со шрифтом? он простой arial стандартный..

Comment: Какие единициы изменения используются кореловском проекте? Может-быть там всё в миллиметрах или дюймах (корел всё-таки больше для печати вроде заточен), а выводится в пиксели с учётом заданного dpi. Был-бы сам svg может чего-то и понял-бы, хотя вряд ли.
Проверяйте единицы измерения. А может это какой-то известный баг корела. Поспрашивайте на профильных форумах.